# Deleting an object without objectId, from REST

Tags: parse-platform

Using REST, I try to delete an object in a Parse.com database, but without directly pointing to the objectId.

Here is the code:

```
deleteFavoriteActivity: function (from, to) {
                var deleteObjects = "?where={\"fromUser\":\"" + from + "\", \"toPro\":\"" + to + "\"}";
                return $http.delete(favoritesActivityUrl + deleteObjects, parseCredentials);
            }
```

As you can see I try to delete object based on a query on 2 fields: "fromUser" and "toPro".
This won't work and return bad request. I don't know if it is even possible to delete object based on query. Is it possible ? Or must I absolutely point to objectID I want to delete ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The endpoint for delete needs an objectid; just get the object with a get request query, get that object's id, then call delete with that id.

Comment: yeah, that's what I guessed, so in the end this is what i'm going to do. Tks